# AWS API Gateway Response Mapping Template not working

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm sure I'm missing something really simple here but is driving me mad! Thanks in advance!

I am setting up a really simple test Api Gateway with a single GET method which triggers an Lambda which returns the following JSON:

```
    {
     "coaches": [
       {
         "name": "Coach1",
         "id": "5"
       },
       {
          "name": "Coach2",
          "id": "7"
       }
    ]
   }
```

When I test the method (in AWS Console) I can see the following log line:

> Wed Feb 05 15:22:48 UTC 2020 : Endpoint response body before transformations: "{\"coaches\":[{\"name\":\"Coach1\",\"id\":\"5\"},{\"name\":\"Coach2\",\"id\":\"7\"}]}"

Which seems fine.

Now I simply want to reformat the output to make it look a bit prettier, so am trying to configure a Integration Response Mapping Template as so:

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5I4Lg.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rL47A.png)

Code below:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
  "coaches": [
#foreach($elem in $inputRoot.coaches)
    {
      "id": "$elem.id",
      "coach": "$elem.name",
    }#if($foreach.hasNext),#end

#end
  ]
}
```

However the next log line in the output is:

> Wed Feb 05 15:22:48 UTC 2020 : Method response body after
>   transformations: {   "coaches": [   ] }

So transformation doesn't seem to have worked. Not sure what I'm doing wrong though?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is with the collection you try to iterate on, and thus the array is empty. There is no `$inputRoot.coaches` collection, as opposed to `params` collection, which is defined under `$input` object. 
An example of extracting the whole query string parameters:

```
{
  "queryStringParameters": {
  #foreach($key in 
   $input.params().querystring.keySet())#if($foreach.index >0),#end
  "$key":"$input.params().querystring.get($key)"#end
   }
}
```

Nevertheless, you can try to extract your `$coaches` collection from the JSON input with the method `$input.json(x)`; this function evaluates a JSON expression, for example: `$input.json('$.coaches')` returns a JSON string representing the coaches structure.

For more details, please refer to [API Gateway Mapping Template documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html)

I also invite you to read my blog-post about API Gateway request parameters: 
[Controlling and Manipulating AWS API Gateway Request Parameters](https://medium.com/devtechblogs/https-medium-com-lior-k-sh-controlling-aws-api-gateway-request-parameters-lambda-function-49b08f96ccd9)